# List shares and ACL's on NETAPP Vfiler

Tags: netapp, powershell

Does anyone know of a Powershell script that will list all shares and their ACL's on a NETAPP vfiler?

Answer (score 3):

The [Data ONTAP PowerShell Toolkit](http://communities.netapp.com/community/interfaces_and_tools/data_ontap_powershell_toolkit?view=overview) has a Get-NaCifsShareAcl cmdlet that'll do just what you want.

```
PS C:\> connect-nacontroller dunn

PS C:\> Get-NaCifsShareAcl | select ShareName -ExpandProperty UserAclInfo
ShareName        AccessRights        UnixGroupName       UserName
---------        ------------        -------------       --------
ETC$             Full Control                            BUILTIN\Administrators
C$               Full Control                            BUILTIN\Administrators
test             Full Control                            everyone
test             Full Control                            DUNN\krusty
test2            No Access                               everyone
test2            Full Control                            DUNN\krusty
HOME             Full Control                            everyone
HOME             rw-                                     root
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe that this works, unfortunately-- you can show the ACLs of shares seen when connecting straight to the controller, but not of vFiler shares so far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Too bad the latest toolkit does not support the retrieval of ACL's.

This error is common and means that this toolkit does not support certain versions of OnTap.

```
PS C:\Users\m0132130> Get-NaCifsShareAcl | select ShareName -ExpandProperty UserAclInfo
Get-NaCifsShareAcl : Unable to find API: cifs-share-acl-list-iter-start
At line:1 char:19
+ Get-NaCifsShareAcl <<<<  | select ShareName -ExpandProperty UserAclInfo
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (clnt-corp-e0475:NaController)
[Get-NaCifsShareAcl], EAPINOTFOUND
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ApiException,DataONTAP.PowerShell.SDK.Cmdlets.Cifs.GetNaCifsShareAcl
```

(Edit: formatting)